# Formatting a time regular expression to require the AM/PM

Tags: java, regex

My regular expression matches a formatted time string of the following types:

```
12:30
12:30 AM
12:30 pm
1:30
1:30 AM
```

((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM))?)

I'm wondering how I can modify the expression to *require* the am/pm? Can anyone offer a hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last '?':

((?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:[2][0-3])|(?:[0-9])):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:\s?(?:am|AM|pm|PM)))